# Normal Subgroup of G Fixes All Elements of Set if G Acts Transitively?

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to prove the following equivalency:

> $H$ is normal in $G$ $\iff$ for any set $\Omega$ on which $G$ acts transitively, if $H$ fixes some $x \in \Omega$ then $H$ fixes every element in $\Omega$.

I am relatively new to studying group theory, and am trying to solve some questions to better understand the definitions. I am slightly more confident with the idea of normality than with the other definitions in the question, but still have no idea how to approach this one from either direction.

Comment: Hint to get you started: for any $y \in \Omega$, since $G$ is transitive, there is some $g \in G$ such that $g\cdot y = x$, where $x$ is the point which $H$ fixes.

Comment: If $K$ is the fix group of $x$, then $g^{-1}Kg$ is the fix group of $gx$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have figured out how to do the rest of that direction using your hint, but am unsure how to prove the hint itself?

Comment: You want to prove $k$ fixes $x$ if and only if $g^{-1}kg$ fixes $xg$. Just do it directly, with a computation. (I'm using right actions.)